# How could I install Ubuntu One on KDE and use it with dolphin?  

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, kde, dolphin

I see in some topics that to install ubuntu-one, I've to execute these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apachelogger/ubuntuone-kde
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-kde
```

However, it don't work (Is ppa:apachelogger/ubuntuone-kde closed ?) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apachelogger/ubuntuone-kde
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 ubuntuone-kde
 tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~apachelogger/+archive/ubuntuone-kde
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.UJpbwWvbov --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver     hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
gpg: « tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted » n'est pas une ID de clé: ignoré
```

How could I install ubuntu-one on KDE and use it with dolphin ?

Comment: You can just use the GTK version although it will look awful in KDE and i don't think there's a plug in of some sort for Doplhin

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One uses Qt for the control panel now, on Ubuntu 12.04. There is no plug-in for Dolphin to provide integration there yet, though. When you upgrade to 12.04, you can simply run the following command, and it will install everything you need.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt

You may still need to have gnome-keyring-daemon running, if kwallet in 12.04 doesn't implement the freedesktkop.org secrets API as gnome-keyring does.

There was a FAQ or Tutorial on the Ubuntu Wiki about this, but I can't seem to find it right now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not even need to use the Konsole to install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.
In Kubuntu 13.10 and the latest builds for 14.04, you can use Muon Discover (under Start > Computer) to find Ubuntu One (actually twice, side by side) in the category of System and Settings. Look for the orange box.
It does not add the check boxes to Dolphin the way it does to Nautilus, but it does 'just work' for me.